# Free in a structure element

Tags: c

Hello I have a question regarding `malloc` and free type of things.

suppose I have a structure with another structure inside it

```
typedef struct All{
    int number;
} A;
```

```
typedef struct Bet{
   A *point; 
} B;
```

Then I create a `B`.

```
B* first = malloc(sizeof(B));
first->point=malloc(sizeof(A));
```

Now lets say I want to make a function that deletes the struct B entirely.

For the delete function I know we have to use
free(first);
So do I also have to free(first->point) or will it disappear automatically if i do free(first);

Comment: If it disappeared automatically, terrible things would happen if some other structure also had a pointer to that block of memory. It would be very difficult to write sane C programs if memory magically freed itself without us asking the implementation to do it whether or not we were still using that memory.

Comment: This is not the question you really want to ask, because you do not want to program using a bunch of rules you forced yourself to memorize. What you really want to ask is what happens when you call `free`, because that gives you the knowledge and understanding to figure out the other question for yourself. What happens when you call `free` is that it releases the block of memory pointed to by the pointer you pass to `free` and nothing else.

Answer (score 3):

I want to add more to what @thisisbenmanley said and build an actual explination that will also show how to wrap part of the code you write.

---

**The basics**

I'll cover just `malloc()` and `free()` here. Whenever you call `malloc()` there should be a `free()` also. Let's take this example with a simple `int`.

```
int *p = malloc(sizeof(int));
*p = 5;
printf("%d", *p);
free(p);
```

It is the same for a struct. Another example:

```
typedef struct Person
{
    int Age;
    int Height;
}Person;

Person* p = malloc(sizeof(Person));
p->Age = 20;
p->Height = 185;
// do something with it ...
free(p);
```

Another very important thing you have to know: `malloc()` can return `NULL` if the allocation fails. It actually means that there is no space to allocate the block. It is very important to actually check for it. For example:

```
int* v = malloc(sizeof(int)*999999999);
if (v == NULL)
{
    printf("Allocation failed.");
    return -1;
}
// Allocation successfull. Do something with the vector ...
```

---

**Structures in structures and structures with pointers**

If structures do not contain pointers just `free()` will do the job. Example:

```
typedef struct Point
{
    int x;
    int y;
}Point;

typedef struct Line
{
    Point a;
    Point b;
}Line;

// this will allocate actually 4 ints
Line* p = malloc(sizeof(Line));

// this is how you access each point's coordinates.
p->a.x;

// do something ...

// this will free both points (the 4 ints)
free(p);
```

Now this is where code can get very unclear depending on each situation. If a structure contains one or more pointers if might prove difficult to keep the code simple to read. Suppose the following struct:

```
typedef struct Person
{
    int Age;
    int Height;
    char* FName;
    char* LName;
    char* Address;
}Person;
```

If you want to allocate a `Person` you need 4 `malloc()` calls. If you also add error checking it will be quite voluminous. Definetly this should be wrapped inside a function:

```
Person* AllocPerson()
{
    // i'm skipping it now so that my point is clear, but checking
    // if malloc returned NULL is recommended
    Person* p = malloc(sizeof(Person));
    p->FName = malloc(sizeof(char)*30);
    p->LName = malloc(sizeof(char)*30);
    p->Address = malloc(sizeof(char)*40);

    return p;
}
```

Now whenever you need a `Person` you can just `Person* p = AllocPerson();`. Same goes with a `FreePerson()` function which will take 4 `free()` calls so that after you finished working with the struct, you simply call `FreePerson(p)`.

```
void FreePerson(Person* p)
{
    free(p->FName);
    free(p->LName);
    free(p->Address);
    free(p);
}
```

You can evolve the `AllocPerson` function even further and turn it into a `Create` function:

```
Person* CreatePerson(int Age, int Height, char* FirstName, char* LastName, char* Address)
{
    // i'm skipping it now so that my point is clear, but checking
    // if malloc returned NULL is recommended
    Person* p = malloc(sizeof(Person));
    p->FName = malloc(sizeof(char)*30);
    p->LName = malloc(sizeof(char)*30);
    p->Address = malloc(sizeof(char)*40);

    p->Age = Age;
    p->Height = Height;
    strcpy(p->FName, FirstName);
    strcpy(p->LName, LastName);
    strcpy(p->Address, Address);

    return p; 
}
```

Now you can just do this whenever you need a person:

```
Person* p = CreatePerson(20, 180, "Alex", "Boris", "Street nr. 5");
```

The `CreatePerson()` function both allocates and initialises fields of a `Person` instance. This aproach of making a `Create` and `Delete` function to a structure is widely used in `C`, especially when you have to use an already made API.

---

**Important notes**

- Always `free()` memory even though after exiting `main()` your OS will take care of the blocks still allocated. This is considered good practice.
- Try to use dynamic memory as less as possible. The Heap is slower than the Stack!
- Try to reuse allocated space whenever possible. Allocating and Freeing are expensive operations!

Comment: The `Alloc*()` and `Create*()` function need to check for returned `NULL`. You wrote this in the beginning but left this *without a note* later.

Comment: Why do you think is Heap slower than Stack? Yes, it has the overhead of `malloc()` and `free()`, but beside that the usage of both is equally fast. In the end it's all memory access.

Comment: 1. Sorry i just forgot to comment the check for NULL in the `Alloc` and `Create` functions. Editing it now.

2. I'm not sure if it applies to `malloc()` or c++ `new` but it definetivelly aplies to the native windows `HeapAlloc()`. When you allocate a lot of memory (not necesarely in one block), behind the scenes virtual memory comes into play. To put it shortly, when you have a huge allocated heap, memory gets placed into actual disk memory rather than RAM. This obviously makes access much slower.

Comment: Right. But if an application needs that much memory that the systems starts to swap, the stack is the wrong place anyway. Oh, and I'm not sure that stack pages are protected from being swapped. -- BTW, please put a @<name> in your response comment to notify the other. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You would also have to `free(first->point)`. When you `free(first)`, all that will deallocate is the bytes holding the struct `first`, which only holds a pointer. That alone will not touch the actual memory address pointed to by `point`; `free(first->point)` beforehand would cover that.